# Persistent data storage in blackerry OS Webworks app

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a mobile app on blackberry webworks platform BBOS 
i know about the different storage provided by HTML5 but the things
is - LocalStorage is limited.
and the data it will store will always be increasing.
What would be a perfect storage  so that when even when the app is closed,
the data will still remain. Also i don't know if websql storage is persistent. 
if a websql database is created, will the data still remain when the app is closed and restarted ?

Answer (score 0):

[Storage - Blackberry Developer](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/beta/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

WebSQL. Yes, the data will still be there. 
You also have partial support for IndexedDB.

And there's a [Local FileSystem API](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/gold/localfilesystem.html) in the Webworks API.

If you need something more customized you can always make your own phonegap plugin.

Comment: also how can i fetch all the contacts from the device phone and sim card (name and number) and store in an array ? i checked the documentation but found nothing of such